# Regex antlr4, what is the command to recognize all symbols?

Tags: regex, antlr4

yesterday and today I tried again antlr4. Now I want to write a regex, which recognize all speical letter like !"$%&/(/(){} etc.

I thoguht I could make it so

```
A: [!"$%&/()]
```

//but the problem is, we have a lot of symbols, also like @, ;, , ,:,'# etc. So a lot of them. How can i say in antlr that i want to recognize all symbols?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just match everything that isn't non-special?  The caret after the first bracket says match everything except the following. For example, `[^a-z A-Z0-9]` matches everything except `a-z`, the space, `A-Z`, and `0-9`.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR supports regex Unicode Categories. So you could try:

```
A : [\p{Punctuation}];
```